# Распаковка ZIP-архива с FTP на PHP

Tags: ftp, php

Как можно zip-архив распоковать через ftp? Так можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу посоветовать использовать онлайновый ftp-клиент, например [net2ftp.com](http://net2ftp.com). Очень удобно, т.к. можно получить доступ из любого места. 
Там есть функция загрузки .zip архива, с автоматической распаковкой в текущую директорию.

Если вы хотите делать это программно у себя на сервере, тогда могу посоветовать библиотеку [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/18).

```
require_once('pclzip.lib.php');
$archive = new PclZip('вашАрхив.zip');
if ($archive->extract() == 0) die("Error : ".$archive->errorInfo(true));
else echo('Ok!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать через какой-нибудь ftp-лиент. Я например, использую net2ftp, но самый простой и популярный - ftpadmin. Скачать можно тут: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpadmin/