# Распаковать zip средствами php

Tags: php

Как лучше распаковать zip?

**Добавлено.**

Ребят, напишите zip класс, пожалуйста! Я вот написал, но что-то не получается, хотя раньше получалось когда не надо!

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip -> open("my.zip") === TRUE)
{
    // Извлекаем файлы 
    $zip -> extractTo("file_time/);
    $zip -> close();
    echo 'Архив распакован';
}
else echo 'Ошибка при извлечении файлов из архива';

               echo "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<";

               echo "<br>";
```

Что-то не пашет(

Comment: это смотря какой объем файлов. Мелкие можно и классами, а большие лучше системными.

Comment: где то 50 мб! как сделать?

Answer (score 1):

[PHP - UnZip on Server](http://www.3scriptz.com/go.php?http://www.3scriptz.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/unzip_on_server.zip) Ковыряйтесь)

Comment: мне нужно автоматом всё! а не чтоб человек выбирал и распаковывал!

Answer (score 1):

[посмотрите тут принятый ответ - там с примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47637/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-zip-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81-ftp-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php)

Comment: у меня работает скрипт так: через ftp вытакскивает zip архив на сервер, потом должен распокавать его! так как файл весит более 50 мб хотелось бы как то оптимизировать!

Comment: думаю, для таких больших архивов нужно использовать gzip, вызывать ее можно функцией system(); gzip - линуксовский архиватор. Хотя, если у вас хостинг, то system() скорее всего запрещен. А если виндовс, то там нет gzip. В таком случае, даже не знаю что посоветовать.

Comment: Скажу больше, если это хостинг, то хостер также может и ограничение на размер файла поставить, значительно меньше.

А вообще юзайте проверенные библиотеки, например PclZip. Зачем изобретать велосипед.

Comment: В принципе зависит от того, какие права у вас на сервере, например для совсем быстрой обработки больших файлов можно Сишные библиотеки заюзать.